# Excel - filter range of data when input matched text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to populate the data when select specific "CREW" initial as shown on the second screenshot below (row 10).

The current formular that I am using is:

```
'=FILTER(A3:D7;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F10;AB3:AB7));"NO RESULT")
```

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot below, when I select "ML" it display what venue he/she was on.

But I would like it to specify what "CREW" number that person was on.

[image]

Thank you in advanced and apologies if the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of frustration with the Dutch version of Excel (I thought I was doing something wrong with the Filter function regardless of translating the functions where needed but Dutch Excel needs to be special with a lot of function names...), I've cracked the code and learned a bit about lambda functions, so not a total loss!

Try this formula in `E3`:

> =BYROW(FILTER(Q3:Z7;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F10;AB3:AB7));"NO RESULT");LAMBDA(array;INDEX($Q$1:$Z$1; MATCH(F10;array;0))))

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You're welcome, happy to learn and give it forward!