# Excel - Changing Filter formular when selecting value from drop down list

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, drop-down-menu

Would it be possible to change "filter" formular when selecting different sheets (on the drop down list)?

The formular I am currently using in `A4`:

```
=FILTER(SOLO!A3:D97;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1;SOLO!AB3:AB97));"NO RESULT")
```

I added the second drop down list `B2` for months selector which I would like it to be linked to each different sheets (January - December).

[image]

For Example - If Crew and Month is selected `B1`& `B2`, the formular then changed to August sheet:

```
=FILTER(August!A3:D97;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1;August!AB3:AB97));"NO RESULT")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need `INDIRECT()` function.

Comment: That works for the sheets selector but it doesn't change anything for the filter formular. @Harun24hr

Comment: But what are you searching actually, cell `A2` refers to the word `Month` are you searching that in other sheet column `AB3:AB97`?

Comment: I assume, you can use this formula as well, if i am not mistaken here: `=LET(x;VSTACK(January:December!A3:AB97);y;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2;INDEX(x;;12)))*(INDEX(x;;3)=C2);TAKE(FILTER(x;y);;4))`

Comment: I am search it in the other sheets within the workbook which will be January sheet through to December sheets. @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: Yes, that I clearly understand you are searching in other worksheets within the same workbook, but as per your formula in the post, cell `A2` is referring to the word `Month`, if i am not wrong. please check. In your screencap - `A1` is `Crew` | `A2` is `Month` | `B1` is `RP` | while `B2` is `August` , the formula which i have given it doesnt needs `INDIRECT()` function as it stacks all the sheets into one, and does the searching with the respective column to give the desired months output.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya My apologies, it supposed to be B1 which is the crew name. But I like to add a function that change the formular when Month is selected after the crew name.

Comment: Then use this it would work let me know : `=LET(x;VSTACK(January:December!A3:AB97);y;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1;INDEX(x;;28)))*(INDEX(x;;3)=B2);TAKE(FILTER(x;y);;4))` this will work, because you already have a month column per your screencap. Provided you need to have `VSTACK()` & `TAKE()` in your version of Excel

Comment: And even `INDIRECT()` function works as mentioned by @Harun24hr Sir, `=FILTER(INDIRECT(B2&"!A3:D97");ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1;INDIRECT(B2&"!AB3:AB97"))))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I have just tried it, and it came up with error. Something to do with "=" and "-"

Comment: Then check whether you are missing any parenthesis or not, even before commenting i tried on my end, and it is working. also I am not sure about your regional settings, per your screencap you are using `semi-colon` as a separator and then formula i have given will work.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya after some messing around, I have got it working now, thank you so much

Comment: You can post it as an answer, the one which worked for you. So it helps someone in the future.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya one more thing, why does it greyed out the first value?

Comment: What do you meant by greyed out.? Please show some screenshots. showing the formula bar as well

Comment: How do I post screenshot on here?

Comment: I have post it on the answer.

Comment: What was the issue? Saw you had posted and then removed the screencap

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorry about that, here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Mayukh Bhattacharya, this worked out perfectly.

```
=LET(
     x;VSTACK(April:March!A3:AB97);
     y;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1;INDEX(x;;28)))*(INDEX(x;;3)=B2);
     TAKE(FILTER(x;y);;4))
```

[image]

Ignore the `#VALUE!`

I still figuring it out how to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, go back to the grey out issue, `#VALUE!` is another formular which I am trying to include it in.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the wb. I have solved the grey out issue.

This is what I  was trying to do on `E4` to generate another value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753544/excel-filter-range-of-data-when-input-matched-text

Comment: I have 2 wait 2 days to accept the answer :(